# How to override functions in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a few install scripts, with almost the same functionality. I separated same functions to include file with common code, but from time to time I need to override some of those.

Unfortunately, `override` at the end as in Delphi doesn't help:

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean; override;
```

Comment: @RobeN, the question is perfectly understandable. IMHO, questions like these deserve upvote (not because they show research effort, but because they are useful), not those like [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23519174/960757), where the OP spent absolutely no time to find a solution by themselves (that question is even a duplicate). It might have been helpful (if there was a way for overriding) even for you when you're using a common code base where certain event methods are utilized.

Comment: FWIW, "override" represents a completely different concept that wouldn't have worked the way you wanted it to anyway.  (No classes.)

Comment: @Miral, e.g. `NextButtonClick` is actually a method! Though I don't know the `Self` object since it is not accessible (I guess the script runner itself), it is a method.

Comment: Yeah, but to be able to override it you need to have it in a subclass.  And you can't declare one of those in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. One thing is that e.g. the [`NextButtonClick`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick) which you mentioned is meant to be the event method whose you do not override; the other is that Inno Setup Pascal Script doesn't support method overriding as such.

The only reliable workaround I can think of is to RY (from DRY), by separating event methods from your common code.

Comment: Tnx a lot, @TLama. Sad that pascalscript is so poor though. I spent some time looking for any possible solution, and after I found nothing that question was kind of desperate move :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ISD specification](http://www.mirality.co.nz/inno/isd.php), which is a suggested method of laying out custom wizard page code in a highly modular and reusable fashion.

It's not generally applicable to all event functions, but it might help you with `NextButtonClick` and other related page events, at least.

(I actually have some code that helps out with merging other event functions somewhat, but it's not really ready for public use yet.)